# Convert TaskCompletionSource to Task.FromResult<TResult>?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have this simple code which start a method asynchronously. it uses `TCS` in order to *wrap* the code with Task.

```
Task<int> DoWork()
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource <int>();
    Thread.Sleep(220);
    source.SetResult(9999999);
    return source.Task;
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);

    var t1=Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoWork());
    t1.ContinueWith(_=>Console.WriteLine ("doing something different "));
    t1.ContinueWith(_=>Console.WriteLine ("finished , value is ="+_.Result.Result));

    Console.WriteLine(2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

output :

```
1
2
doing somethign different  //those last 2 lines can be swapped
finished , value is =9999999
```

But now , I want to convert it to use `Task.FromResult<TResult>`.

This is [poorly documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx)  , so I wonder  , how can I convert my code above to use `Task.FroResult` instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use `FromResult` would be to do:

```
public Task<int> DoWork()
{
    return Task.FromResult(99999);
}
```

But it's an exact functional equivalent of doing:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
tcs.SetResult(99999);
return tcs.Task;
```

so it doesn't sleep for 220 ms. For the 'delayed' variant, easiest way would be:

```
public async Task<int> DoWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(220);
    return 99999;
}
```

and this version behaves close enough to the example you provided.

Comment: Actually it is not like my example . Myne has a blocked thread somewhere due to sleep, while yours doesnt since task. Delay uses timer which is not blocking

Comment: @RoyiNamir True enough, it's asynchronous wait, not blocking wait, but since you're now playing with async&await, a general rule of the tumb is that you should not wait synchronously. Unless you want to spend time solving deadlocks :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Yes, but that doesn't mean you should say that is behaves *exactly* the same.

Comment: @svick Right, you're technically correct (the best kind of correct). I have made a small edit to reflect that. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you return the `Task` only after the synchronous wait is over, so your code is equivalent to:

```
Task<int> DoWork()
{
    Thread.Sleep(220);
    return Task.FromResult(9999999);
}
```

But if you returned the `Task` immediately and then blocked some other thread:

```
Task<int> DoWork()
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(220);
        source.SetResult(9999999);
    });
    return source.Task;
}
```

(Note: I'm not saying you should do this in real code.)

This code couldn't be simulated by `Task.FromResult()`, because that always creates an already completed `Task`.